# Chrome downloads 60 times slower than wget?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, wget

I just downloaded a large file (the [KyngChaos PostgreSQL package](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres), an 8.5MB file).

In Chrome, it was downloading at less than 1KB/sec, and said it would take over an hour to arrive.

When I tried downloading it through wget, it downloaded at 60KB/sec and was ready in under a minute.

This is clearly an issue with Chrome rather than with my internet connection (I was running the two simultaneously), so what's going on?

I'm using MacOS Lion and Chrome 19.0.1084.52.

Comment: Did you perform repeated checks (not downloading simultaneously) and averaged the speed? Otherwise your hypothesis about Chrome being slower can't really be verified.

Comment: It's not a hypothesis, it's a problem report.

Comment: Well, have you really tried it more than once? One time with Chrome only, with `wget` only, not simultaneously? Does it happen even if you try it multiple times?

Comment: 8.5MB is a large file...?

Comment: The scenario you're describing sounds completely bizarre, maybe a freak occurrence. Has it happened again? Is it reproducible?

Comment: *This is clearly an issue with Chrome rather than with my internet connection [...]* I don't think so. Connections may get rate limited when established on the server or client (read: ISP) side for a number of circumstances. Chances are that aborting the connection and restarting the download will fix the problem.

Comment: Perhaps Chrome is picking up a weird proxy configuration...  Is there anything interesting under Chrome -> [wrench] -> Settings -> Advanced -> Network, Proxy Settings?